# Allure is not reporting failures properly with exception( nosuchelementexception )

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

1. `krGlobalPage.softAssertionTestCall2(softAssertion);` has to run even after `krGlobalPage.softAssertionTestCall1(softAssertion);` is failed due to

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have found best - and also to show in Allure report as fail - is to try-catch the findelement and in the catch block, set the assertTrue to false, like this:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//nav[@class='topline']//nav[@class='without-seperator1']/a)[1]");
}catch(Exception e) {
    assertTrue(false, "Test Search link was not displayed");
}
```